# executing commands when user first logs in

Tags: ldap

So I use webmin to create ldap user. I then manually create public_html folder, and set quota for newly created home folder. Is there a way such that I can execute commands when user first logs in or is there a way I can automatically set quota and create folders when user is created through webmin?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set up Home directory** The common approach is to set up the template of your new user's home directory in /etc/skel.

Than you enable the PAM module pam_mkhomedir which will create the home directory for a user the first time they log in (if it's not yet present) From the man page:

> The pam_mkhomedir PAM module will create a users home directory if it does not
>     exist when the session begins. This allows users to be present in central database
>     (such as NIS, kerberos or LDAP) without using a distributed file system or
>     pre-creating a large number of directories. The skeleton directory (usually
>     /etc/skel/) is used to copy default files and also sets a umask for the creation.

where the pam_mkhomedir module is enabled exactly depends on your distribution, but for example on RHEL6 it would be the file `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` where you would add a line

```
session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required    pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

with the correct template directory (/etc/skel) and umask.

**Quota** Setting quota depends on the underlying file system, IIRC on the EXT[2-4] filesystems you must explicitly set quota's for each (new) user, but XFS allows you to set a default quota value for every unique user on each XFS file-system.

**pam_exec** Allows pam to run specific commands each time a user logs on. You could create a script (which replaces the steps above) that checks if the users home directory exists, if not prepare the home directory, configure quota and whatever else you want to set up.

```
session required pam_unix.so
session required pam_exec.so /sbin/setup_newuser.sh $PAM_USER
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use .bash_profile or .bashrc to execute commands in a users home directory.

   2. To Customize a new users home directory you need to modify the skeleton under /etc/skel .

[Using /etc/skel](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/using_skel.htm)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not very much webmin-like, but it will save you a lot of clicking work in the future because of automation.

You can automate the whole process of creating home-dirs and generating a default login script:

- LDAP how-to for Ubuntu regarding generation of home-folders and some other useful configuration issues. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication#Automatically_create_home_folders
- In the directory /etc/profile.d/ you can put a script like "login_script.sh" which will be started after every login by each user.
- For the quota issue, adapt the suggested mkhomedir part in the ubuntu tutorial with the manual here http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-journaled-quota-on-debian-lenny

The links I gave are for Ubuntu, but I believe that for other major distributions it is not very much different.